# Как осуществить фоновую подгрузку ресурсов?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Необходимо во время загрузки приложения подгружать ресурсы (множество мелких изображений), таким образом, чтобы это происходило в фоновом режиме, не видимо.

Чтобы после полной загрузки приложения и подгрузки ресурсов, выбранные формы отображались моментально, и не тратили время на подгрузку ресурсов.

В примере ниже, код, с помощью которого при нажатии на `pictureBox` происходит стирание `panelMain`, чтобы отобразить нужную форму:

```
    // Отображение формы "Control" для меню "Управление"
    private Form f1;
    private void pictureBoxControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.panelMain.Controls.Clear();

        if (f1 == null)
        {
            f1 = new FormControl();
            f1.TopLevel = false;
            f1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }

        this.panelMain.Controls.Add(f1);
        f1.Show();
    }
```

Comment: Ну создайте отдельный поток/задачу и загружайте в фоне. Можно в потокобезопасную коллекцию (словарь), откуда потом брать уже загруженные ресурсы.

Answer (score 0):

Решение:

```
namespace MySoft
{
    public partial class FormMain : Form
    {
        public FormMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        // Переменные для форм
        private Form f1;
        // Загрузка главной формы
        private void FormMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Загрузка фоновых форм
            if (f1 == null)
            {
                f1 = new FormControl();
                f1.TopLevel = false;
                f1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            }

            this.panelMain.Controls.Add(f1);
            f1.Show();
            f1.Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

Только остается вопрос, какое скрытие формы использовать:

```
f1.Visible = false;
```

или

```
f1.Hide();
```